# IntPtr WndProc no suitable method found to override c#

Tags: c#, wndproc

i was trying to override this `WndProc` in my win form application but got error `IntPtr WndProc no suitable method found to override`. my code as follows

```
protected override IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg == NativeCalls.APIAttach && (uint)lParam == NativeCalls.SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_SUCCESS)
            {
                // Get the current handle to the Skype window
                NativeCalls.HWND_BROADCAST = wParam;
                handled = true;
                return new IntPtr(1);
            }
            // Skype sends our program messages using WM_COPYDATA. the data is in lParam
            if (msg == NativeCalls.WM_COPYDATA && wParam == NativeCalls.HWND_BROADCAST)
            {
                COPYDATASTRUCT data = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
                StatusTextBox.Items.Add(data.lpData + Environment.NewLine);
                // Check for connection
                //if (data.lpData.IndexOf("CONNSTATUS ONLINE") > -1)
                  //  ConnectButton.IsEnabled = false;
                // Check for calls
                IsCallInProgress(data.lpData);
                handled = true;
                return new IntPtr(1);
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

anyone can guide me what i am missing. thanks

Comment: You are getting your class libraries mixed up.  That's an override for the HwndHost.WndProc() method, only used in WPF apps.  Winforms uses the *Message* struct.  Just let IntelliSense autocomplete the override for you, can't mess it up that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use this WndProc in Windows Forms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220111/how-to-use-this-wndproc-in-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature is incorrect, [`Form.WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you are overriding returns `void`.

`protected virtual void WndProc(ref Message m)`

I don't know where you got that code, port from C++ maybe? but it won't work with a WinForms form.

Comment: just see this url http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/browse/Source/SharpDX/Win32/MessageFilterHook.cs?name=2.4.2 and here u will see same kind of wndproc signature used.