# Wnd Proc related issue

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

Here is my WndProc. I am expecting that when I am calling through Skype from my apps then controls should come to this `if` block repeatedly but I saw only it coming once.

```
if (m.Msg == NativeCalls.WM_COPYDATA && m.WParam == NativeCalls.HWND_BROADCAST)
```

Where am I making a mistake? Can anyone guide me?

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    Boolean handled = false;
    if (m.Msg == NativeCalls.APIAttach && (uint) m.LParam == NativeCalls.SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_SUCCESS)
    {
        // Get the current handle to the Skype window
        NativeCalls.HWND_BROADCAST = m.WParam;
        handled = true;
        m.Result = new IntPtr(1);
    }

    // Skype sends our program messages using WM_COPYDATA. the data is in lParam
    if (m.Msg == NativeCalls.WM_COPYDATA && m.WParam == NativeCalls.HWND_BROADCAST)
    {
        COPYDATASTRUCT data = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
        StatusTextBox.Items.Add(data.lpData + Environment.NewLine);

        // Check for connection
        //if (data.lpData.IndexOf("CONNSTATUS ONLINE") > -1)
        // ConnectButton.IsEnabled = false;

        // Check for calls
        IsCallInProgress(data.lpData);
        handled = true;
        m.Result = new IntPtr(1);
    }

    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (handled) DefWndProc(ref m); else base.WndProc(ref m);
    //base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

here i attach the link of my win application and that is https://onedrive.live.com/#cid=C4A6F16F34D7540A&id=C4A6F16F34D7540A!126 just download the skypecalltest and run it.

before run my apps just login to skype and then run my apps where you put a phone no and click on call button then you can see the controls is not coming repeatedly to the second if block.

so what i need to change in my code as a result control will come to second if block.

in the same link there is another same kind of apps which is based on wpf. that is working where `wndproc` is calling repeatedly. if possible check that code too and guide me what i am missing or making mistake. thanks
thanks

Comment: You are calling `base.WndProc(ref m);` twice when `handled` is `false`.

Comment: @Ashigore : sorry that was typo.

Comment: very easily anyone can catch the problem if they download two zip files from the link i specified. the win apps is developed by me which i inspired by wpf apps. both can be downloaded from that link. thanks

Comment: I made some change in my answer to your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220111/how-to-use-this-wndproc-in-windows-forms-application/23220236#23220236)... Maybe the problem is because `m.Result` always returns zero, so I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

What O/S are you running this on?

If Windows 7 or later, your application may need to explicitly opt into receiving WM_COPYDATA messages by calling ChangeWindowMessageFilter or [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: if u go to the link which i provide in my question then u can see SkypeRecording.zip file is there. just download it and see the code there is no ChangeWindowMessageFilter function used there but that apps works fine. i develop a similar type of apps which is win apps but that is not working.

Comment: Unlikely, he wouldn't get the first one if that were necessary.  UIPI doesn't have a "works once" mode.

Comment: @Hans Passant : what u try to say not clear. what r u trying to mean "he wouldn't get the first one if that were necessary" ?